# Flipping or rotating pads?

Tags: disc-brake, frugal, brake-pads

I went to replace the pads on my front mechanical disc brake.

I noticed the pad on the stationary side had significantly less wear than the pad on the actuated side.

Could I get away with flipping the left pad with the right pad to get more life out of them?

[Stationary Pad](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ACtC-3exxXO-lG2AzS7rS6vPQ6tyBmqnWjiLInGAX7XSQsdNmy1QTzNNNDhPl3KlJSooXW6aqScQBWmhD-__Vd0vNIwywO4REmOb0OfRYrf_N1ljnMLFL5F4eJep-qjH_4dErqH4xGbVMzn5eBD8m7Tbfi3rSQ=w1443-h1083-no)
[image]

[Actuated Pad](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ACtC-3cGsoxlVLHjG-Addl_vsaOEgGjLDzXXEgXDphRHq1f_GPmLiFYzeATfAvELCUvUQFlIngtG-IKMo1L4y0srNT7yGygvZwfIo2wY073isilpM0QOY-VcCt2h9ZEpA5IzFTMRNSWC_wxnSsR-FLOigqbsJQ=w1443-h1083-no)
[image]

Edit:

Pads: Tektro A10.11

Calipers: https://www.mate.bike/us/product/tektro-mechanical-disc-brake-set-mate-x/ can't find the model number

This is on the front wheel.

Comment: That's a great question - are they mirrored pads?

Comment: Also consider that brake pads are consumable, and replacing pads is cheaper and better than replacing rotors damaged by scoring.    Why is your pad, pad backing, and caliper all the same colour - is this the colour of the landscape where you ride?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as they are not different.

It makes sense that the actuated side wears more as it does most of the work.

Just bear in mind that some pads are directional, but you haven't posted which pads you're usring.

One thing you should think about though, is how far the static pad can be pushed. Some cheaper mechanical brakes only have a limited amount of movement and if you bottom that out, then actuated side won't be able to push far enough to hold it. Again, this is a general statement as I don't know which calipers you are using.

---

Edit

You can physically swap the sides from Tektro A10.11 pads. Everything else from above still applies, ie about brake caliper limits.

Answer (score 2):

Hold on !
It looks like one of the pads is worn in an angle ?
If so, I wouldn't swap it as you risk losing braking power as only part of the pad surface would bite.
If you have enough material, you can sand it down for it to be level again.

If i'm correct at least, as i'm looking at the pic on mobile in bright sunlight.
:)
Bernie